# UIButton with increasing height if width is not enough?

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

I need a button to set up via `autolayout` which **height will increase** if the horizontal space is not enough **i.e. after rotation**. I have a leading and trailing constraint to the parent view, and in portrait mode there is lack of space, so I was thinking about not to reduce font size, but increase height and set `Word Wrap` for `Line Break`. I was experimenting `size classes`, but in somehow always the `wCompact hAny` is used, because I am testing in iPhone. So to set different height for button for different size classes had no effect.

Anybody has idea how to set depending button height on the available button width and the content via autolayout constraint?

On iPhone button below needs two lines, not 30px, but appr. 60px.

[image]

Comment: @janos- what can be the max width of the button...?

Comment: there is no "max width" it is depending which device app is running on

Comment: @janos- you have to decide what will be the max width of the button.

Comment: I would not do it programmatically with `sizeWithAttributes` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am suspicious it is not possible with Interface Builder I made it with subclassing an `UIButton`:

```
class DynamicHeightButton: UIButton {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let size = (self.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal)! as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)], context: nil)
        self.bounds.size.height = size.height + 8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a button? This is not what a button is for. If you have that amount of text to display then use either a `UILabel` or `UITextView`. You can then add a gesture recogniser to it to capture the tap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UILabel` and can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` on it. and set number of lines=0 in nib file and have one action of tap gesture. it will work like a button with almost no code as u want